# How to provide read access to implementers of a protocol while others have write access in Swift

Tags: swift2

I'd like to provide read access for certain properties to all classes/structs that implement a protocol while client classes of the protocol are allowed read+write access. Is there a way to do this in Swift?

```
protocol WheelsProtocol {
    var count: Int {get set}
}

struct Car: WheelsProtocol {
    var count: Int = 0

    func checkTirePressure() {
        // Here, we will iterate over the count of wheels but we should
        // not allow the number of wheels to be changed
    }
}

struct CarFactory {
    var wheels: WheelsProtocol

    init(wheels: WheelsProtocol) {
        self.wheels = wheels
    }

    mutating func configureVehicle() {
        self.wheels.count = 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a protocol for car makers and a different one for cars,  something like

```
protocol MakesCars {
    var wheelCount: Int {get set}
}

protocol HasWheels{
    var wheelCount: Int { get }
}

struct Car: HasWheels {
    let wheelCount: Int

    init(wheelCount: Int) {

        self.wheelCount = wheelCount

    }

    func checkTirePressure() {
        // Here, we will iterate over the count of wheels but we should
        // not allow the number of wheels to be changed
        wheelCount = 5 //COMPILER ERROR
    }
}

struct CarFactory: MakesCars {
    ...
}
```

The key is that you have to define a read-only property in the protocol as a `var` with `{ get }` but in the object that adopts that protocol you have to put `let` and set it in an initializer.

Comment: FYI - This does not actually limit access to the setter for wheelCount on Car.  There's nothing stopping any consumer of this API from casting to Car and calling set.

Comment: I understand what you mean because the OP used the word "access", which would indicate something related to APIs, but in my opinion that's not what the OP was asking about. I looked directly at what the OP was trying to accomplish in the given code and offered a solution. Given that the answer was accepted, I can only assume that I understood the goal correctly, however inaccurate the wording of the problem. Nonetheless, if the OP now wanted to know how to accomplish a similar goal in relation to API access, I humbly defer to your previous answer.

Comment: Your answer is fine, I wasn't trying to say you were incorrect.  I just wanted to put a note on there so people wouldn't assume it was somehow actually limiting access to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to limit access to a particular method in the way you're describing.  From [the documentation on Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3):

> Swift provides three different access levels for entities within your
>   code. These access levels are relative to the source file in which an
>   entity is defined, and also relative to the module that source file
>   belongs to.
>
> Public access enables entities to be used within any source file from
>   their defining module, and also in a source file from another module
>   that imports the defining module. You typically use public access when
>   specifying the public interface to a framework.
>
> Internal access enables entities to be used within any source file
>   from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a
>   framework’s internal structure.
>
> Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining
>   source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of
>   a specific piece of functionality.

To accomplish this, you would need to create a separate module (i.e., a Framework) and limit the writes to the `internal` scope and make the reads of the `public` scope.

Comment: Is this feasible at the protocol level with the existence of CarFactory? What would the syntax look like? I know about access setters on classes/structs (internal(set/get)) but something similar at the protocol level?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Protocols just define a contract of methods/properties that an adopting type must implement, they don't provide any additional access control in terms of exposing or not exposing those methods/properties.  What I suggested was that you make a framework and keep all the setter methods (and other things not for the client of the API) internal while you make the parts of the API you want to expose to clients public.